# How to save multiple output values received from For Loop of one script to variables.robot

Tags: python, list, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework, Selenium in Pycharm. I want;

1. To save multiple return values in different variables.
2. These variables I need in variabls.robot.
3. After that I want to fetch these values one by one from variables.robot in the for loop of different scripts.

Below is the requirement example.

I have below web table which I access in my first script.

[image]

1. I want to navigate through all the rows and get the values of Product ID one by one (In first script). Here I am using loop to get the values and processing it.
2. Then want to save all the Product IDs in different variables in variable.robot file
3. Finally want to call these product IDs in multiple other scripts. In few scripts I need one or two id's and in couple of scripts I need them to bring one by one in loop.

I was thinking about list but not able to acheive it.

**1.Suggest if any solution is with list too.**

**2. Want to know how to save multiple outputs received from For Loop to different variables.**

**3. also want to know how to save these values from first script to variables.robot so it will be easy call these values any other scripts.**

```
@{list}   Create List
    Append To List   ${list}   ${ProductID}
```

I am getting list in one script but how to send it to variables.robot or call these values one by one in other scripts.

Comment: you should include code you've tried.  Does .robots file need to be in a specific format?  It sounds like you'll just be using arrays/lists... probably more of a set/dictionary kind if those Product IDs are unique.  Then decide on a file format for storage... I'd consider using an XML format.  (or use something like POI which can read/write excel files, which are a specific format of XML.)  It's more flexible and you can have forwards compatibility.  You might also consider using a database depending on your needs.